# How to get more than 10K logs/results in Elasticsearch

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, kibana, nest, elasticsearch-dsl

How could I go about getting all the logs if lets say I have more than 10K logs/results with the latest version of Elasticsearch (7.13)? I was reading up on [scroll search results](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/paginate-search-results.html#scroll-search-results) but at the beginning it shows:

> We no longer recommend using the scroll API for deep pagination. If
> you need to preserve the index state while paging through more than
> 10,000 hits, use the search_after parameter with a point in time
> (PIT).

But with [search_after](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/paginate-search-results.html#search-after) it says you can access more than 10,000 hits but you would need to use a [point in time api](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/point-in-time-api.html#point-in-time-api) in order to get the PIT (point in time) ID then pass that ID to the search_after parameter. In kibana CLI if you type in the cmd `POST /YOUR PATTERN INDEX NAME*/_pit?keep_alive=1m` it will return that PIT ID. But how would you go about doing that command in NEST for .net client?

[This](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/point-in-time-usage.html) only tells you what to do if you already have the PIT ID but does not show you how to do the post command to get the PIT ID? Is there a way to do so without having to go to Kibana -> Discover -> CLI and running the command `POST /customer-simulation-es-app-logs*/_pit?keep_alive=1m` (customer-sim is the name of my index)

---

*Before implementing Rob's sample I had the following:*

```
[HttpGet("GetMonthlyLogs")]
        public async Task<List<EsSource>> GetLogsByDate()
        {
    
            string indexName = "customer-simulation-es-app-logs*";
            var connectionSettings = new ConnectionSettings(new Uri("http://localhost:9200"));
            connectionSettings.DefaultIndex(indexName);
            connectionSettings.EnableDebugMode();
            _elasticClient = new ElasticClient(connectionSettings);

            // this will return the number of results in the index based on the criteria below:
            var responseHits = _elasticClient.Count<EsSource>(c => c
                 .Query(q => q
                     .Bool(b => b
                         .Should(
                               m => m
                               .Match(ma => ma
                                   .Field(fa => fa.level)
                                   .Query("Error")),
                               m => m
                               .Match(ma => ma
                                   .Field(fa => fa.level)
                                   .Query("Information")))
                         .Filter(f => f.DateRange(dr => dr
                         .Field("@timestamp")
                             .GreaterThanOrEquals("2021-07-16T12:46:00.227-05:00")
                             .LessThanOrEquals("2021-07-16T12:55:00.227-05:00")))
                         .MinimumShouldMatch(1)))).Count;

            var response = await _elasticClient.SearchAsync<EsSource>(s => s
                  .Size(3000) // must see about this
                  .Source(src => src.Includes(i => i
                                    .Fields(f => f.timestamp,
                                            f => f.level,
                                            f => f.messageTemplate,
                                            f => f.message)))
                  .Index("customer-simulation-es-app-logs*")
                  .Query(q => q
                      .Bool(b => b
                          .Should(
                                m => m
                                .Match(ma => ma
                                    .Field(fa => fa.level)
                                    .Query("Error")),
                                m => m
                                .Match(ma => ma
                                    .Field(fa => fa.level)
                                    .Query("Information")))
                          .Filter(f => f.DateRange(dr => dr
                          .Field("@timestamp")
                             .GreaterThanOrEquals("2021-07-16T12:46:00.227-05:00")
                             .LessThanOrEquals("2021-07-16T12:55:00.227-05:00")))
                          .MinimumShouldMatch(1))));


            return response?.Documents.ToList();
        }

public class EsSource
{
       [Date(Name = "@timestamp")]
        public DateTimeOffset timestamp { get; set; }
        public String level { get; set; }
        public String messageTemplate { get; set; }
        public String message { get; set; }

}
```

---

**I attempted to give Rob's sample implementation a stab, what I did was the following. However, my question is if I do not have the "ID" that is inside of EsDocuments can I use `timestamp` instead? The `foreach` is needed because that will group the results into 1000 correct? Can I also sort by timestamp or does it strictly have to be the result ID? Since I do not have an `ID` I was thinking to make another `var searchResponse` that uses the searchapi, but then create a general variable named EsID so I can for loop through searchResponse within hits so like `foreach(var item in searchResponse.Hits(){ EsID = item.Id }` then use it for the `foreach` that has batch (`batches.Select(x => EsID)`) and use it for the sort. But I felt like that would be repetitive code... correct me if I am wrong?**

Please see my implementation here:

```
private IElasticClient _elasticClient;

[HttpGet("GetMonthlyLogs")]
       public async Task<List<EsSource>> GetLogsByDate()
       {
           
            string indexName = "customer-simulation-es-app-logs*";
            var connectionSettings = new ConnectionSettings(new Uri("http://localhost:9200"));
            connectionSettings.DefaultIndex(indexName);
            connectionSettings.EnableDebugMode();
            _elasticClient = new ElasticClient(connectionSettings);

             // this will return the number of results in the index based on the criteria's 
            var responseHits = _elasticClient.Count<EsSource>(c => c
                 .Query(q => q
                     .Bool(b => b
                         .Should(
                               m => m
                               .Match(ma => ma
                                   .Field(fa => fa.level)
                                   .Query("Error")),
                               m => m
                               .Match(ma => ma
                                   .Field(fa => fa.level)
                                   .Query("Information")))
                         .Filter(f => f.DateRange(dr => dr
                         .Field("@timestamp")
                             .GreaterThanOrEquals("2021-07-16T12:46:00.227-05:00")
                             .LessThanOrEquals("2021-07-16T12:55:00.227-05:00")))
                         .MinimumShouldMatch(1)))).Count;

           

            foreach (var batches in Enumerable.Range(0, (int)responseHits).Batch(1000))
            {
                var bulk = await _elasticClient.IndexManyAsync(batches.Select(x => new EsSource { /* can I use timestamp?? */}));
            }

            await _elasticClient.Indices.RefreshAsync();

            var openPit = await _elasticClient.OpenPointInTimeAsync(indexName, d => d.KeepAlive("1m"));
            var pit = openPit.Id;

            var searchAfter = 0;

            try
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    var response = await _elasticClient.SearchAsync<EsSource>(s => s
                          .TrackTotalHits(false) // disable the tracking of total hits to speed up pagination
                          .Size(1000)
                          // pass pit id & extend lifetime of it by another minute
                          .PointInTime(pit, d => d.KeepAlive("1m"))
                          .Source(src => src.Includes(i => i
                                              .Fields(f => f.timestamp,
                                                      f => f.level,
                                                      f => f.messageTemplate,
                                                      f => f.message)))
                          .Query(q => q
                              .Bool(b => b
                                  .Should(
                                          m => m
                                          .Match(ma => ma
                                              .Field(fa => fa.level)
                                              .Query("Error")),
                                          m => m
                                          .Match(ma => ma
                                              .Field(fa => fa.level)
                                              .Query("Information")))
                                  .Filter(f => f.DateRange(dr => dr
                                  .Field("@timestamp")
                                      .GreaterThanOrEquals("2021-07-14T00:00:00.000-05:00")
                                      .LessThanOrEquals("2021-07-14T23:59:59.999-05:00")))
                                  .MinimumShouldMatch(1)))
                          // can I assort with timestamp or does it have to be the result ID?
                          .Sort(srt => srt.Ascending(f => f.timestamp))
                          .SearchAfter(searchAfter));

                    if (response.Documents.Count == 0)
                    {
                        break;
                    }


                    //searchAfter = response.Documents.LastOrDefault()?.timestamp ?? x;
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                // closing the pit
                var closePit = await _elasticClient.ClosePointInTimeAsync(d => d.Id(pit));
            }

            return // response?.Documents.ToList();
        }


    public class EsSource
    {
        [Date(Name = "@timestamp")]
        public DateTimeOffset timestamp { get; set; }
        public String level { get; set; }
        public String messageTemplate { get; set; }
        public String message { get; set; }        
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've prepared a sample app with comments which demonstrate how to retrieve all docs from an index using PIT and search after.

```
class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        string indexName = "test";
        var connectionSettings = new ConnectionSettings(new Uri("http://localhost:9200"));
        connectionSettings.DefaultIndex(indexName);
        connectionSettings.EnableDebugMode();
        var elasticClient = new ElasticClient(connectionSettings);

        await elasticClient.Indices.DeleteAsync(indexName);
        var indexResponse = await elasticClient.Indices.CreateAsync(indexName);

        // index some test data
        // Batch coming from morelinq nuget
        Console.WriteLine($"Index some data into index");
        foreach (var batches in Enumerable.Range(0, 20000).Batch(1000))
        {
            var bulk = await elasticClient.IndexManyAsync(batches.Select(x => new EsDocument {Id = x }));
        }

        await elasticClient.Indices.RefreshAsync();

        var countResponse = await elasticClient.CountAsync<EsDocument>(d => d);
        Console.WriteLine($"Documents in index: {countResponse.Count}");

        Console.WriteLine($"Open new pit");
        var openPit = await elasticClient.OpenPointInTimeAsync(indexName, d => d.KeepAlive("1m"));
        var pit = openPit.Id;

        Console.WriteLine($"Read all docs from index ..");
        // we will start reading docs from the beginning
        var searchAfter = 0;
        try
        {
            while (true)
            {
                var searchResponse = await elasticClient.SearchAsync<EsDocument>(s => s
                    // disable the tracking of total hits to speed up pagination.
                    .TrackTotalHits(false)
                    .Size(1000)
                    // pass pit id and extend lifetime of it by another minute
                    .PointInTime(pit, d => d.KeepAlive("1m"))
                    .Query(q => q.MatchAll())
                    // sort by Id filed so we can pass last retrieved id to next search
                    .Sort(sort => sort.Ascending(f => f.Id))
                    // pass last id we received from prev. search request so we can keep retrieving more documents
                    .SearchAfter(searchAfter));

                // if we didn't receive any docs just stop processing
                if (searchResponse.Documents.Count == 0)
                {
                    break;
                }

                Console.WriteLine(
                    $"Id [{searchResponse.Documents.FirstOrDefault()?.Id}..{searchResponse.Documents.LastOrDefault()?.Id}]");
                searchAfter = searchResponse.Documents.LastOrDefault()?.Id ?? 0;
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Close pit");
            var closePit = await elasticClient.ClosePointInTimeAsync(d => d.Id(pit));
        }
    }

    class EsDocument
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Prints

```
Index some data into index
Documents in index: 20000
Open new pit
Read all docs from index ..
Id [1..1000]
Id [1001..2000]
Id [2001..3000]
Id [3001..4000]
Id [4001..5000]
Id [5001..6000]
Id [6001..7000]
Id [7001..8000]
Id [8001..9000]
Id [9001..10000]
Id [10001..11000]
Id [11001..12000]
Id [12001..13000]
Id [13001..14000]
Id [14001..15000]
Id [15001..16000]
Id [16001..17000]
Id [17001..18000]
Id [18001..19000]
Id [19001..19999]
Close pit
```

Comment: Thank you for providing the sample! Does the `await elasticClient.Indices.DeleteAsync(indexName);
        var indexResponse = await elasticClient.Indices.CreateAsync(indexName);` deletes the existing logs and creates a new one? Can I skip this part I do not want to delete any existing logs

Comment: Yes, definitely you can skip this part, that's just for setting up test data.

Comment: Awesome I follow, will skip it thank you!

Comment: If you don't mind can you please view my updated post? I have somethings I need clarification on and guidance! Thanks! :)

Comment: @MarkCo `timestamp` field will work fine as well.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. An issue I am running into is the line where you have `searchAfter = searchResponse.Documents.LastOrDefault()?.Id ?? 0;` since I am using `timestamp` field and `searchAfter` is of type int, when I do the following: `searchAfter = searchResponse.Documents.LastOrDefault()?.timestamp ?? 0;` it tells me **operator ?? cannot be applied to operands of type 'DateTimeOffset' and 'int'.** Is there a work around this? I tried to find a solution to this error but couldn't find one.

Comment: You can replace it with `DateTime.Min` in your case. It doesn't really matter as the program won't reach there because we check above for `searchResponse.Documents.Count == 0`.

Comment: as in set `searchafter = DateTime.Min`? When I was debugging it, the first iteration of the while loop the system did reach that part and displayed the console.writeline portion of it (I commented out that line that consisted of the ?? operator). On the second iteration of the while loop it did break however. My searchResponse.Documents.Count was 50 on the first iteration, second iteration was 0. Is that supposed to happen?

Comment: On another note, just wanted to double check with you. `Console.WriteLine($"Index some data into index");
        foreach (var batches in Enumerable.Range(0, 20000).Batch(1000))
        {
            var bulk = await elasticClient.IndexManyAsync(batches.Select(x => new EsDocument {Id = x }));
        }

        await elasticClient.Indices.RefreshAsync();
` these lines of code was just for your testing purposes correct as for me it is not needed?

Comment: Yes, that's just for testing.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to add `PointInTime` instance to your search query, like this:

```
esQuery.PointInTime = new PointInTime(PointInTimeId,KeepAlive);
```

your first request to ES your `PointInTimeId` will be null, for more information check ES official documentation [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/point-in-time-usage.html).

Comment: How would you send the first request for your `PointInTimeId` though? That's my question...

Comment: You make the query you want and set PoinInTime the result you get back will give you PoinInTimeId.